# How to show all logs in a file in web api

Tags: c#, .net, logging, asp.net-web-api2, log4net

I have created an `API`.Via [Web API Tracing using Log4net](https://dotnettrace.net/2013/09/08/web-api-tracing-using-log4net-dll/) I have created a log file. But in this file, only some logs are shown which are successful. But I want to show all possible events i.e. all `stack trace` in my log with `line number`. Below is what I have done

**Created an API Tracer Class**

```
namespace ActualWebService
{
 public class MyAPITracer : ITraceWriter
 {
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyAPITracer));
    public void Trace(HttpRequestMessage request, string category, TraceLevel level, Action<TraceRecord> traceAction)
    {
        TraceRecord rec = new TraceRecord(request,category,level);

        traceAction(rec);

        WriteLog(rec);


    }

    private void WriteLog(TraceRecord  rec)
    {
        string strLog = string.Format("{0};{1};{3}", rec.Category,rec.Operator,rec.Operation,rec.Message);
        log.Info(strLog);

    }
}
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net" />        
    // other.....
   </configSections>
    <log4net>
        <root>
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
        </root>
        <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <param name="File" value="E:\MyLog\LogFile.txt" />
            <param name="AppendToFile" value="false" />
            <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
            <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
            <CountDirection value="1" />
            <staticLogFileName value="true" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
            <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %meesage%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <logger name="ApiLog">
            <level value="ALL" />
        </logger>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

config.Services.Replace(typeof(System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriter), new MyAPITracer());
```

Below is my log file contents

```
2018-07-07 14:23:05,593 [1] INFO  ActualWebService.MyAPITracer - 
System.Web.Http.Controllers;WebHostHttpControllerTypeResolver;eesage
2018-07-07 14:23:05,614 [1] INFO  ActualWebService.MyAPITracer - 
System.Web.Http.Controllers;WebHostHttpControllerTypeResolver;eesage
2018-07-07 14:23:22,793 [8] INFO  ActualWebService.MyAPITracer - System.Web.Http.Request;;http://localhost:14909/api/meters/GetByMsn/002997001022/ 
2018-07-06T11:10:43eesage
2018-07-07 14:23:22,793 [8] INFO  ActualWebService.MyAPITracer - System.Web.Http.MessageHandlers;PassiveAuthenticationMessageHandler;eesage
2018-07-07 14:23:22,803 [8] INFO  ActualWebService.MyAPITracer - System.Web.Http.Controllers;DefaultHttpControllerSelector;Route='controller:meters,action:GetByMsn,msn:002997001022,dt:2018-07-06T11:10:43'eesage
2018-07-07 14:23:22,806 [8] INFO  ActualWebService.MyAPITracer - System.Web.Http.Controllers;DefaultHttpControllerSelector;Meterseesage
2018-07-07 14:23:22,807 [8] INFO  ActualWebService.MyAPITracer - System.Web.Http.Controllers;HttpControllerDescriptor;eesage
2018-07-07 14:23:22,808 [8] INFO  ActualWebService.MyAPITracer - System.Web.Http.Controllers;DefaultHttpControllerActivator;eesage
2018-07-07 14:23:23,145 [8] INFO  ActualWebService.MyAPITracer - System.Web.Http.Controllers;DefaultHttpControllerActivator;ActualWebService.Controllers.MetersControllereesage
2018-07-07 14:23:23,146 [8] INFO  ActualWebService.MyAPITracer - System.Web.Http.Controllers;HttpControllerDescriptor;ActualWebService.Controllers.MetersControllereesage
```

I created an exception/error but it is not shown in my log file. How can I show all of my stack trace in it with the line number?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `WriteLog` method.

In this method class [TraceRecord](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/hh944889(v=vs.118)) is used and you can log error from the this class.

Review my implementation of this method:

```
private void WriteLog(TraceRecord rec)
{
    if (rec.Exception == null)
    {
        string infoLog = string.Format("{0};{1};{3}", rec.Category, rec.Operator, rec.Operation, rec.Message);
        log.Info(infoLog);
    }
    else
    {
        string errorLog = string.Format("{0};{1};{3}", rec.Category, rec.Operator, rec.Operation, rec.Message);
        log.Error(errorLog, rec.Exception);
    }
}
```

After you can see Error log:

```
2018-07-09 14:23:44,561 [11] ERROR TestErrorLogging.MyAPITracer - System.Web.Http.Controllers;TestController;eesage
System.Exception: Test Exception
   в TestErrorLogging.Controllers.TestController.Get() в C:\Users\Александр\Desktop\TestErrorLogging\TestErrorLogging\Controllers\TestController.cs:строка 15
   в lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   в System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   в System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   в System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerTracer.<ExecuteAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()
```

Comment: How can I add line number ?

Comment: And how can I add all the methods like warning etc

Comment: @MrFaisal you can see line number on Exception Stack Trace. `TestErrorLogging.Controllers.TestController.Get() в C:\Users\Александр\Desktop\TestErrorLogging\TestErrorLogging\Controllers\TestController.cs:строка 15`. **15** it is a line number.

Comment: yes but it only shows line number when there is an exception. What if I want to show line number for each type of logs.

Comment: In this case you can log full StackTrace using [Environment.StackTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx) property. As example: `string infoLog = string.Format("{0};{1};{3};{4}", rec.Category, rec.Operator, rec.Operation, rec.Message, Environment.StackTrace);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer it helps me out :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Alexander I. says, you have to use the different log methods like Info(), Warn(), Error(), etc.

Here is a further link with some useful information about log4Net:

https://stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging/

For execption handling/tracing in asp.net web api you could also use an ExceptionFilter (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling).

Answer (score 1):

The line numbers in your exceptions stacks are coming from the PDB files. Look at your build configuration of your release. [ Project Properties | Build ] -> Advanced button - > Debugging information dropdown

Full or PDB-only should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the stack trace for *every* log message, you could use `%stacktrace` or even `%stacktracedetail` in your pattern layout:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline%stacktrace%newline" />
</layout>
```

See [the docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Layout_PatternLayout.htm) for more info.